# Django Paginator gives error __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'number' and 'paginator'

Tags: python, django, django-pagination

I have used the following code from Django Documentation and for some reason the code doesn't work

```
<div class="pagination">
 <span class="step-links">
        {% if productsList.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ products.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ productsList.number }} of {{ productsList.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if productsList.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ productsList.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ productsList.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

When I go to the page I get the error :

```
__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'number' and 'paginator'
```

Strange! 
I have also tried passing on the url with page argument but it still doesn't work!

```
def products(request):
    products_first_ten = Products.objects.order_by('productid')[:100]    
    products_List = []
    for product in products_first_ten:
        book = Books.objects.get(productid = product.productid)
        products_List.append(book)      

    paginator = Paginator(products_List, 10) # Show 25 contacts per page
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    try:
        products_List = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        products_List = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        products_List = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(
        request, 'catalog/products.html',
        context = 
        {
            'productsList' : products_List
        }
    )
```

Comment: Show your `view` code.

Comment: You need to show the full error. What init is it referring to?

Comment: It's resolved! I had an issue with one of the variables! Thanks!